# Stacking list column in data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data frame with list column:

```
a <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c"))
a$col2 <- list(list(),list(name="Michal", age=28), list(name="Johnny", age=31))
```

I'd like to merge these columns together as a data frame so the desired output would look like below data frame:

```
  col1   name     age
1  a     NA       NA
2  b     Michal   28
3  c     Johny    31
```

For transforming list column into data frame I'm using

```
plyr::ldply(a$col2, data.frame)
or
lapply(a$col2, data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

but unfortunately it'll skip empty list in first position:

```
   name   age
1 Michal  28
2  Johny  31
```

Is there any trick, how to keep this empty list for further cbind().

Comment: Try with that `list(name=NA, age=NA)` instead of  `list()` for the first line

Comment: There is a system which is generating this empty list so I don't wanna do these manual stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `unnest`, it supposes that col1 is a unique index (for the `left_join`) and that your lists are either `NA` or contain only `name` and `age` in the same order :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyR)
a  %>% mutate(col2 = lapply(col2,unlist)) %>%
  unnest %>%
  cbind(key = c("name","age")) %>%
  spread(key,col2) %>%
  left_join(a,.) %>%
  select("col1","name","age")

#   col1   name  age
# 1    a   <NA> <NA>
# 2    b Michal   28
# 3    c Johnny   31
```

It'd be more general and elegant to change NULL lists to `list(NA,NA)` as a first step (then ugly `left_join` could be avoided), but I couldn't manage to do it.

EDIT:

Found a way to do it, though I'm sure first line could be improved :

```
library(magrittr)
a  %>% mutate(col2 = inset(col2,lengths(col2) == 0,list(list(NA,NA)))) %>%
  mutate(col2 = lapply(col2,unlist)) %>%
  unnest %>%
  cbind(key = c("name","age")) %>%
  spread(key,col2)
```

EDIT2 :

Another one much more straightforward (skip first line if you're fine with `NULL` instead of `NA`):

```
a %>% mutate(col2 = inset(col2,lengths(col2) == 0,list(list(name=NA,age=NA)))) %>%
  mutate(name = sapply(col2, "[[", "name"),
         age  = sapply(col2, "[[", "age")) %>%
  select(-col2)
```

Comment: This is also great solution, thank you very much for that!

Comment: I found a way to get rid of the left join by replacing NULLs in the first step, see updated solution

Comment: This is really very cool! I like your first edited solution. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I cannot figure out what kind of package inset function belongs to... Could you give me a hint, please.

Comment: oh sorry, it's `magrittr`, i'll add it

Comment: Is there any way, how to change edited solution to avoid the following error message: Duplicate identifiers for rows ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, are you sure that col1 is unique and that all lists are regular ? (2 elements, age and name, or NULL)

Comment: you can execute the pipe chain step by step (stopping before `%>%` at each step) and report which line is problematic

Comment: I found some work around and it works great. Thank you very much once again!

Answer (score 6):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, unlist(col2, recursive = FALSE), col1][a[, "col1", with = FALSE], on = .(col1)]
#   col1   name age
#1:    a     NA  NA
#2:    b Michal  28
#3:    c Johnny  31
```

---

If we need a `tidyverse` option

```
library(tidyverse)
a$col2 %>% 
    set_names(a$col1) %>% 
    Filter(length, .) %>% 
    bind_rows(., .id = "col1") %>% 
    left_join(a[1], .)
#   col1   name age
#1    a   <NA>  NA
#2    b Michal  28
#3    c Johnny  31
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very cool solution in data.table. Is there any way how to do that by dplyr package?

Comment: @martinkabe  Updated with a dplyr option

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can automate the suggestion of Orhan Yazar with `lapply` to check for length, fill in the proper list elements, and then combine to get the result.

```
# fill in empty list items of col2
a$col2 <- lapply(a$col2, function(x) {if(length(x) == 0) x <- list(name=NA, age=NA); x})

# build new data.frame
data.frame(col1=a$col1, do.call(rbind, a$col2))
  col1   name age
1    a     NA  NA
2    b Michal  28
3    c Johnny  31
```